# Cache Intersystems %TIMESTAMP error

Tags: timestamp, intersystems-cache, intersystems

I'm new to `Intersystems Cache` and getting the following error returning a `%Timestamp` property from a Web Service i'm calling through a `.NET` Application:

```
[System.FormatException] = {"The string '2012-11-22T20:00Z' is not a valid AllXsd value."}
```

Does anyone know how I can reformat the `%Timestamp` property to a European Date/Time format before returning it?

Thanks,

O.

Answer (score 0):

The code that is doing this is found in the `LogicalToXSD` class method of the `%Library.TimeStamp` class.  Looking at the code, it is not intended to support different Date/Time formats.

You could change the property from being of data type `TimeStamp` to data type `EuropeanTimeStamp`, a class you create as a subclass of `%Library.TimeStamp`.  You could then override the `LogicalToXSD` and `XSDToLogical` methods.

Obviously whatever format you use is the format all consumers of the web service will get.

You might also be able to handle this on the `.NET` side.  If you can tell whatever is consuming the webs service that the property in question is a string then you can convert it to Date/Time later.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using SOAP? 
If so have a look at the [LogicalToXSD(..)](http://docs.intersystems.com/ens20122/csp/documatic/%25CSP.Documatic.cls?PAGE=CLASS&LIBRARY=%25SYS&CLASSNAME=%25Library.TimeStamp#LogicalToXSD) method. (And consider the parameter XMLTIMEZONE).

If you just need to convert the actual value [$ZTS is your friend](http://docs.intersystems.com/ens20121/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=RCOS_vztimestamp)